Where did the "simulate this circuit" link go?
In recent responses I've written, which include circuits created using the CircuitLab.com editor/simulator, the "simulate this circuit" link that usually accompanies the schematic image is gone.
Often the ability to simulate a described circuit directly from the answer can be extremely useful.
Is this a bug? Is the link gone for good, and if so, why?

While it is a trivial circuit, my answer which was created on 20th April 2024 after the the migration to https://i.sstatic.net as the image service provider is showing a simulate this circuit link. On the referenced answer in which "simulate this circuit" is still showing the picture of the schematic was uploaded to https://i.stack.imgur.com, whereas the other pictures were uploaded to https://i.sstatic.net

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Yesterday I also noticed that "Simulate this circuit" below schematics disappeared. I have asked a similar question on Meta SE.

I'm looking into this right now - I'm the one who implemented the update for our circuitlab integration to use the new image service. So, my apologies! Do you think you could link me an example that you've found where the simulate this circuit link is missing?

@kristinalustig See my most recent answer. It could also be that I'm not seeing the link because it's my answer.

Thank you so much - I'm also not seeing it. I'll keep you all updated once I have a fix ready.

And here I thought circuit breaker meant something else entirely! :P

Thank you for the bug report! There was one place I missed that had a hard-coded imgur URL which was preventing the message from appearing. I've shipped the fix, so new circuits will work fine.
Because there were posts created while this was not working, I had to manually reprocess those. I think I caught all of them, but if you find any that do not have the 'Simulate this circuit' link below, please just let me know. Sorry again for breaking this and thanks for your patience while I fixed it!
